# Including Pictures in a Post

Tags: discussion

Often times I include pictures in my posts to prove a point.

Should I use an external source to host the images or should I use the upload feature?

I ask because there are countless posts that use the built-in picture uploader; however there are tons that don't as well:

- [Wordpress permalink is not working when set to postname](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36207521/3998484)
- [Score totals adding incorrectly javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36192336/3998484)
- [how do I wrap my menu in to sub menu using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36204044/3998484)

(just to list a few I found quickly)

Are we supposed to use the internal one?

If no, why may it be better to use an external one?

If yes, what should I do if I see one that *isn't* hosted internally?

Answer (score 36):

You should use the upload feature - as long as you have the right to do that.

This creates a copy of the image (which is why you need to have the right to copy the image) on `stack.imgur` which is guaranteed<sup>*</sup> not to expire.

Linking to the existing image (or one uploaded to another file sharing site) runs the risk of the image disappearing and thus making the post less useful.

If you see a post that doesn't use the `stack.imgur` account then don't upload it yourself - you won't have the rights. If the link is broken leave a comment for the OP telling them this so they can fix it. If the link's not broken - do nothing at all, there's no point in moving the image at this point.

<sup>* As much as anything can be guaranteed.</sup>

Comment: Good point on the rights. I've (very rarely) migrated an image to SO/imgur hosting myself. Guess I shouldn't have done that.

Comment: A side question, do you know if we can retrieve all post that got image linked not from imgur ? I ask as I seen another post today with a broken image, sadly it make the question.irrelevant now (I would re upload those image before they expire in big)

Comment: @yagmoth555 you can search for posts containing a URL. See the advanced search options.